# why setTimeout's callback parameter can take parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js

In nodejs, why can we pass parameter to setTimeout's callback function.
I know, `process.nextTick()` crashed as aspected, cause it take an undefined value as an function.
But, what's the magic is going on with `setTimeout()`?

```
foo = function(a){
  console.log(a);
}
setTimeout(foo('hello'), 0); // work fine
process.nextTick(foo('hello'), 0); // TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using:

```
setTimeout(foo('hello'), 0);
```

You are executing `foo`, and passing the result (`undefined`) to the `setTimeout`.
This means that, the exact moment `setTimeout(foo('hello'), 0);` is run, `"hello"` will be logged, but not because the timeout has ended.

This is your code, but with a 10 second delay. Notice how the code immediately alerts `"hello"`, instead of after 10 seconds:

```js
foo = function(a){
  alert(a);
}
setTimeout(foo('hello'), 10000);
```

`foo('hello')` is immediately invoked when setting the timeout, instead of after the specified delay.
To pass parameters to a timed out function, you'll need to wrap the function call in a function:

```js
foo = function(a){
  alert(a);
}
setTimeout(function(){
    foo('hello');
}, 1000);
```

This way, the `foo` function will only be called *after* the timeout has finished.

The reason you get `TypeError: undefined is not a function` on `process.nextTick(foo('hello'), 0);` is the same. `foo('hello')` is executed, returns `undefined`. This return value is passed to `process.nextTick`. You should also wrap that in a function:

```
process.nextTick(function(){
    foo('hello');
}, 0);
```

The reason `setTimeout` isn't crashing, is that it doesn't mind `undefined` as function parameter:

```js
setTimeout(undefined, 0)
```

You'll see it doesn't log any errors.

Comment: I think u misunderstood me. Have tried my code in node? `setTimeout(foo('hello'), 0)` works just fine, it will print out `hello`

Comment: @bpceee: I added some extra explanation to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your quick and accurate reply. It seems `process.nextTick` do not check if it's arguments's is a function or not.

Comment: @bpceee: Indeed, that appears to be the case. You're welcome! And thanks for accepting this answer :-)